# ls and actual file size without using 'long listing format'

Tags: files, ls

The Linux `ls` command comes with these options.

```
   --block-size=SIZE
          scale sizes by SIZE before printing them; e.g., '--block-size=M' prints sizes in units of  1,048,576  bytes;  see
          SIZE format below


   -l     use a long listing format

          list subdirectories recursively

   -s, --size
          print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
```

I presume that `ls -l` is the actual file size and `ls -s --block-size=1` is the amount of disk space allocated to storing the file. (In this case 991232 = 968x1024 = 968K.)

```
$ ls -s --block-size=1  summary.pdf 
991232 summary.pdf
$ ls -l summary.pdf 
-rwxrwx---. 1 chris chris 989838 May  1  2015 summary.pdf
```

Is there an to get the file size in bytes without the additional information in "long listing format"?

Comment: `du -s summary.pdf` gives the same output as `ls -s --block-size=1 summary.pdf `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `stat` with a custom format.

```
stat -c'%s' summary.pdf
```

will output the actual file size in bytes. If you want allocated blocks, use `%b` for the number of blocks allocated and `%B` for the block size of each block in bytes.

This also works with wildcards and an additional `%n` for the file name. See the man page for more format options.

Comment: define "actual file size".  The real "actual file size" is the size in blocks (or in multiple block, depending on the file system), which is the real space allocated in the disk.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: actual file size = what's in the `st_size` field of the inode = what counts when you access the file through read(2), write(2) etc. I chose the wording because it was used in the question itself for the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: Yes, for my purposes I have a lot of large files & I am looking for duplicates. I want to first get a list of file sizes & then do an md5sum on them. So actual file size means character length of the file, not allocated block storage.

Comment: So thanks, @dirkt now I can do this: find /mnt/pdffolder -name 'summary.pdf' -exec stat -c'%n %s' {} \; > file_list

Comment: If you use something like `'%011s %n'` instead (or even more than 11 digits if necessary), you can also `sort` it by size, which may help with finding duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an alternative `ls` format which shows just size and filename, this hack does the trick.

```bsh
ls -l | sed "s/  */ /g" | cut -d ' ' -f 5,9-
```

or maybe:

```bsh
alias size_plus_name="sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 5,9-"
ls -l | size_plus_name
```

Use `ls` with any switches or command line arguments this way. Do not forget to include `-l`.

*Attention!* This only works if filenames does not contain any whitespace.
However, `5-9-` (instead of `5-9`) makes an attempt to handle wsp-containing filenames.
(cf. @Scott 's comment below)

Comment: This fails for filenames that contain space(s), not to mention newline(s).  [In general it’s a bad idea to parse the output from `ls`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Hm.. Thank you. You are generally right. I was not aware this, because I never name files with wsp in the name. Sorry. If I get files from an external source I tend to rename them if their names contain wsp. All in all, I think it is good practice not to have wsp in filenames. See e.g. [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355908) os [this](https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-tech). Edited my answer.

Comment: OK, it still won’t be perfect, but you can make your answer better just by adding a **`-`**, resulting in ``cut -d ' ' -f 5,9-``.  That will output the 5th and 9th fields — and the 10th and the 11th, etc. …, if they exist.

Comment: @Scott Thank you. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`du` replace * with filename:

```
du -s -B 1 *
du -s -B 1 * | cut -f 1
```

it's the same as `stat` except for directories: `du` will report recursive size (ex:99999), `stat` will report 4096 or block size

---

`find` also works: same as `stat`

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -printf "%s\n"
```

```
%p     File's name.
%s     File's size in bytes.

%f     Print the basename; the file's name with any leading directories removed
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html